# Brother printer udev config error:: systemd-udevd[514]: /etc/udev/rules.d/60-brother-libsane-type1-inst.rules:14 Invalid key 'SYSFS'

Tags: usb, udev, brother

I see this error in my journal.

```
 systemd-udevd[514]: /etc/udev/rules.d/60-brother-libsane-type1-inst.rules:14 Invalid key 'SYSFS'
```

The rules file *seems* to be about USB but I don't understand all its references so I can't say for sure.

Fact: the printer is not connected via USB but by wifi so possibly I don't need this problematic file? Or perhaps the problem is that udev is looking for a printer on a USB but finds none so ...

The printer works very well and there is no other indication of problem but I'd like to know. I don't like to see errors in the journal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of this error is:

"1. SYSFS is long deprecated and has been removed with udev-173
it should be replaced by ATTR or ATTRS to match any parent device."

If you look in /etc/udev/rules.d/60-brother-brscan4-libsane-type1.rules you will see that the next rule correctly uses ATTRS! It could be that both were in for a transition period, or it could be that someone just forgot to delete the SYSFS rule.

Bottom line; The SYSFS rule can be safely deleted.